# what's the difference: /etc/nfs.conf vs /etc/sysconfig/nfs in RHEL/CentOS 7

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, nfs, nfsv4

in RHEL 7.9, there is `/etc/nfs.conf` and `/etc/sysconfig/nfs`.

why the two?

which one should be edited, and should one and not the other be edited ?

It seems `/etc/nfs.conf` has more in it, but both have references to the same items such as a mountd port number for example.

does one supercede the other? {for example if I set a mountd port to 1234 in one then set a mountd port to 2345 in the other}

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/sysconfig/daemon` normally contains daemon launch options.

`/etc/daemon/*` or `/etc/daemon.conf` contain full daemon configuration.

Certain daemons allow to specify *all* their option as launch options, others don't.

As to what overrides what depends on a particular daemon.